# Possible to encrypt system.web/membership/providers in Web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I have been able to encrypt other sections of the Web.config file, but this section continues to throw an error stating, "The configuration section 'system.web/membership/providers' was not found."

Is it possible to encrypt this section of the Web.config file?

1. The section exists
2. I have checked MSDN and related forums
3. I googled for many-a-moons
4. I am using aspnet_regiis.exe to do the encryption programmatically by spawning a process in a C# console application.

```
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = ASPNET_REGIIS;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    ... more code ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system.web/membership/providers` is not a configuration section, it refers to an element within the [System.Web.Configuration.MembershipSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.membershipsection(v=vs.110).aspx) section.

You need to encrypt the whole membership section.